# Is it possible to create library for Java & JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, maven, npm

Im angular developer.

In our front & back exists some magic calculation methods.

Classes same, but when anyone find bug in calculation need to fix it in two different projects.
maybe there is a way to create a generic codebase (maby function) that can be converted to js(or ts) & java and update two libraries based on the two results obtained

Comment: You could probably implement it in JS and then Java can call the JS code. That way both can consume the same code. But...I'm not sure why you have two implementations to begin with. Normally what should happen is the opposite - the frontend *doesn't do the calculation*. The backend handles it and the frontend just sends requests to get the value. That way you have 1. a single source of truth. 2. Nobody can fiddle with the calculations on the client-side 3. you ensure the accuracy of results does not differ because JS doesn't have integer division or similar small things.

Comment: need get calculated values fast that becouse i try to search solution without calling REST API, but thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use kotlin.

Kotlin [transpiles to JavaScript](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-overview.html#new-kotlin-js-ir-compiler) and also [compiles to java bytecode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-get-started.html#create-an-application).

However, you can only access kotlin utilities and neither access java or JS/TS types if you want to use the code in both java and ts/js code but you can use [the kotlin stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/).

But if it really is just a calculation, you may not need java/js specific classes/functions.

However, as [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) mentioned in the comments, you should consider doing the calculation only once in the backend.

#### Setting this up in IntelliJ

You can create such a project in IntelliJ by sekecting `Kotlin` in the `New Project` Window and using the project template `Library`.

[image]

Make sure you have the targets `common`, `jvm` and `js`. Since you didn't say you would do native stuff, you don't need the `native` target.

[image]

You can then use the kotlin library in both JavaScript (e.g. Angular) and Java projects as a dependency.

From a Java project, you can reference `KOTLIN_PROJECT/build/classes/kotlin/jvm/main` (this directory contains compiled Java classes).

From a JavaScript (e.g. Angular) project, you can reference `KOTLIN_PROJECT/build/js/packages/kotlinToJavaAndJS`.

As a proof of concept, I have made [this repository on GitHub](https://github.com/danthe1st/KotlinToJavaAndJS).